# DNN Version 5.6.2 on windows server 2012 r2

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

We are using DNN Version 5.6.2 in our application and the application is running properly on windows server 2008 r2 with IIS Version 7.0, SQL 2008 R2, Visual studio 2010 and Net framework 4.0.

Now plan is to upgrade the current windows server i.e. 2008 r2 with windows server 2012/ 2016 or 2019.

Question is : what prerequisites will be required for the DNN Version 5.6.2 to make application compatible with upgraded version i.e. Windows server 2012/2016/2019.

Thanks & regards
Alok Kumar Pandey

Answer (score 1):

You have to install .Net Framework 3.5 and ASP.Net 3.5. This can be done by selecting "Add roles and features" from the "Manage" menu in Server Manager. You may find more information in the [DNNDocs Guides](https://dnndocs.com/content/guides/tutorials/setup/set-up-iis/index.html).

Anyway, I would strongly recommend to upgrade your DNN installation, as DNN 5 is quite old and there are [security issues](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community/security/security-center).